# Assign a value to a cell depending on content of another cell - Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the IF function to assign a value to a cell depending on another cells value

[image]

So, if the value in column 'E' is 1, then the value in column G should be the same as F

But, if the value in column e is 2, then the valuein G should be 10

Would someone be able to show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the new IFS function if you have Office 365.

```
=IFS(E2=1,F2,E2>=2,10)
```

Or for versions that don't have IFS()

```
=if(E2=1,F2,if(E2>=2,10,""))
```

Edit: To change the value from F2 to a negative number, multiply it by -1.

```
=if(E2=1,F2*-1,if(E2>=2,10,""))
```

Comment: The second one worked a charm - If I wanted to change the figures to negatives (providing the value in e is 1) how would I go about that?

Comment: I added that scenario to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CHOOSE(MATCH()) Function:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(E2,{1,2}),F2,10)
```

[image]

or a simple IF:

```
=IF(E2=1,F2,10)
```